# How to move rows from one spreadsheet tab to another tab based on MULTIPLE CONDITIONS using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I want to move rows from one spreadsheet tab to another tabs (within same spreadsheet) based on MULTIPLE conditions using Google Apps Script.

I have multiple tabs for different team members, in which their corresponding lead details are logged. After calling the leads, I move that particular rows to different tabs (Bad leads, Closed leads and Sold leads). I have been able to move rows from each member tabs to different lead statuses back and forth with the help of script.

```
from Kushal tab to Closed leads tab <==> from Closed leads tab to Kushal tab
from XYZ tab to Bad leads tab <==> from Bad leads tab to XYZ tab
and so on.
```

Basically, I know how to move rows based on only one condition; whether the lead status is either Bad or Closed or Sold or Processing.

But my problem is: I have multiple member tabs from where multiple lead rows can be transferred to any one of the tabs (Bad, Closed or Sold) and I want to revert back the rows  to the member tabs where it originally came from, based on Team Member column value (Kushal, XYZ, ABC, etc.).

```
if lead status = processing and team member = Kushal,
then, move row from Bad leads tab to Kushal tab.

else if lead status = processing and team member = XYZ,
then, move that row from Closed leads tab to XYZ tab.

else if lead status = processing and team member = ABC,
then, move that row from Sold leads tab to ABC tab.
```

**Can anyone please help me with this?
Please let me know if my question is not understandable.**

Here is the script I have that transfers one row to multiple tabs back and forth, based on only one condition.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "lead list" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Closed Leads") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("closed leads");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
else if(s.getName() == "lead list" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Bad Leads")
{
  var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("bad leads");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
}
  else if(s.getName() == "lead list" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Sold")
{
  var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sold");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
}
  else if(s.getName() == "closed leads" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Pending") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("lead list");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "closed leads" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Bad Leads") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("bad leads");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "closed leads" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Sold") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sold");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "bad leads" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Pending") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("lead list");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "bad leads" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Closed Leads") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("closed leads");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "bad leads" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Sold") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sold");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "sold" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Pending") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("lead list");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "sold" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Bad Leads") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("bad leads");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if(s.getName() == "sold" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Closed Leads") 
  {
    var row = r. getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("closed leads");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that providing your current script and the current issue of script will help users think of the issue and solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike , I have updated the question with my current script, please take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. Although I try to understand about your question from your updated question, unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Can you just take one case at a time and explain the problem in more detail describing with the multiple factor are.  Keep in mind we can't see your spreadsheet.  Also don't expect us to follow a link to a spreadsheet.

Comment: I think this monosnap screenshot would help explain my question:
https://monosnap.com/file/ldjCZ5lI2hazlZPOID8HD2FVNuaonW

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with the current script? Do you get any error? Or is it behaving differently from what you expect?